# Downgraded php version , now casues error Call to undefined function

Tags: php

https://github.com/akalongman/php-telegram-bot

i installed it with composer , everything was working fine

but now i needed to downgrade because for able to use mysql_* functions.

now when i try to run the script i get this error

```
Call to undefined function Longman\TelegramBot\mb_strlen() in C:\xampp\htdocs\vendor\longman\telegram-bot\src\Request.php on line 366
```

here is the code

```
public static function sendMessage(array $data)
{
    if (empty($data)) {
        throw new TelegramException('Data is empty!');
    }
    $text = $data['text'];

    $string_len_utf8 = mb_strlen($text, 'UTF-8'); # << 366. line
    if ($string_len_utf8 > 4096) {
        $data['text'] = mb_substr($text, 0, 4096);
        $result = self::send('sendMessage', $data);
        $data['text'] = mb_substr($text, 4096, $string_len_utf8);
        return self::sendMessage($data);
    }
    return self::send('sendMessage', $data);
}
```

i dont see any error , why php engine serches mb_strlen function under the class?

Comment: Because the function probably doesn't exists (you should install the mb extension).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably forgot to enable this extension [which is *not* enabled by default](http://php.net/manual/en/mbstring.installation.php):

> mbstring is a non-default extension. This means it is not enabled by
>   default. You must explicitly enable the module with the configure
>   option. See the Install section for details.
>
> The following configure options are related to the mbstring module.
>
> --enable-mbstring : Enable mbstring functions. This option is required to use mbstring functions.
>
> libmbfl is necessary for mbstring. libmbfl is bundled with mbstring.
>   If libmbfl is already installed on the system, --with-libmbfl[=DIR]
>   can be specified to use the installed library.

Comment: yes right,i just confused when it looked under the class